# Gson Maven dependency not loading correctly

Tags: java, gson, maven-2

I've been scratching my head over this for the past hour or so. I can't seem to figure out how to use Gson via Maven's dependency manager. Everything I've seen online seems to indicate that I need to add a few lines to my `pom.xml` file. So I have this so far in there:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

It doesn't seem to do anything though. Building the project doesn't result in any build failures, but running the program catches an exception. The output is as follows:

```
$ java -cp target/Animation-Game-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar core.App
Hello World!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder
    at core.sprite.Sprite.toString(Sprite.java:136)
    at core.App.main(App.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the scope of the library.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hasn't changed anything unfortunately. I'm not sure what's causing this..

Comment: Did you refresh your dependencies?
Right-click on your project then Maven > Update Snapshots.

Comment: I believe I did. I'm not using an IDE, so I'm not sure what to click to do that. But I did run a few commands (which I believe did that) to no effect. The commands I ran were: `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` and then `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install`

Comment: I would suggest to use an IDE.
How are you executing your program? You are probably executing it without that library.